# Documentation - the problem with examples

Tags: discussion, documentation

I was looking at the documentation site and it seemed to me that my Q&A [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21974361/what-java-collection-should-i-use) about java collections would be useful documentation.

However the emphasis on examples means that a more abstract thing like that doesn't really fit into the model.

So is that sort of guide just not a good fit?

Or should I contrive some examples?

Or is there some other approach entirely to use?

Answer (score 5):

Adopt the Wikipedia model: Be Bold.

The "rules" say that an example is supposed to be code. Well, the title says "Documentation", so adding documentation, whether code or not, is in the spirit of the site. Put whatever you feel is most appropriate there and let others judge your contributions.